# basic Javascript While loop and boolean value questions

Tags: javascript, while-loop, boolean

I would ask my instructor, but whenever I do, he gives me an even more vague answer to my questions, so I'm asking yall for help. We "learned" (i.e. watched videos) about for and while loops and I get it, I feel like I do, but whenever it comes to doing the assignments given, I feel like they don't make sense. Like back in math class in high school, they'd teach you about the problems, but then when it came time to do your homework, the problems were completely different from what you just learned about. For instance, it says the basic while loop structure is:

```
while(condition is true) {
 //do something
}
```

But then in this assignment, it gives me:

```
// Another way to write a while loop is to have a boolean variable 
// where the condition goes and then test every time if you need to
// change the boolean to false.

// Below we have a variable lessThan5 and it is set to true.
// Create a loop that tests if our variable 'j' is less than 5.
// If it is less than 5 then Increment it by 1. If it is not 
// less than 5 then set our lessThan5 variable to be false.
let lessThan5 = true;
let j = 0;

while(lessThan5) {
}
```

We didn't learn anything about using boolean values in while loops and I feel like I'm meant to infer what to do, and what structure to use and I just have no idea. Aside from the fact I feel like the instructions to many of these questions are poorly worded, which only confuses me more!

So then there's this third one:

```
// Example of what the number game would look like:
// Couple things to note:
// Math is a built in object in javascript.
// Math.round() will round a decimal number to a whole number.
// Math.random() returns a decimal number between 0 to 1.
// (But not including 1)
function guessNumberGame(guess) {
  let guessing = true;
  let number = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
  while(guessing) {
    if(guess === number) {
      guessing = false;
    } else {
      guess = Number(prompt("That number didn't work. Try again: "));
    }
  }
}

// Problem 3
// We will give you a number through the 'num' parameter
// Create a while loop that will loop 'num' amount of times.
// For example if num is 3 then your while loop should loop 3 times
// If num is 20 then the loop should loop 20 times.
// Increment k every loop.
let k = 0;
function keepLooping(num) {

}
```

If this Problem 3 is meant to be related somehow to the number game example, I can't see it. I don't even know what it is I need to be asking. Does this make any sense to anyone? And nobody else is publicly asking questions about any of this, and it's making me feel stupid and like I am the only one too dumb to get what's going on. I was doing really well and ahead of schedule with all this until this point, but just none of this is making any sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to programming, JavaScript (JS), and StackOverflow (SO)!

Let's dive into this a little deeper. First, a quick JavaScript primer: in JavaScript, everything can be classified as either an *expression* or a *statement*. At a super high and not-technical level:

***expression***: something that produces a value
***statement***: an instruction to the computer

(For a much longer explanation, see [here](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/javascript/statements-vs-expressions/))

Often, *statements* have slots that can take *expressions*. Loops are a great example of that.

For example, `1 + 1` is an expression, since it produces the value `2`. Even more simply, `1` on its own is also an expression, since it produces the value `1`. `while(/*some expression here*/)` is a *statement* that has a slot for an *expression*. `for(s1, e2, e3)` is also a *statement* that has slots for *statements* and *slots*.

So, the `while` loop acts on an expression, and will continue to loop as long as the value returned by that expression is truthy. truthy and falsey is an interesting concept in JavaScript and can be a whole essay on it's own, but the tl;dr of it is that anything that `== true` is truthy, and anything that `== false` is falsey

So for your first question, `0 < 5 == true`, while `5 < 5 == false`. Thus, if you make the value of `j` be greater than or equal to 5, the loop will break.

```js
let lessThan5 = true;
let j = 0;

while(lessThan5) {
  // For each cycle of the loop, check if `j` is less than 5
  if (j < 5) {
    // If `j` is less than 5, increment it
    j++; // This is equivalent to saying j = j + 1, or j += 1
  } else {
    // If `j` is not less than 5, set `lessThan5` to `false`
    // Not when the loop goes to iterate again, `false == false`, and it stops
    lessThan5 = false;
  }
}
```

I think given the above you should be able to solve the third problem. Please let us know if you have trouble with it, show us what you try, and we'll be happy to help some more :)

Comment: let k = 0;
function keepLooping(num) {
 while (num < 3);
  k++;
} else { (num < 20)
k++;
}
This is the best I could do for the third problem. But it just keeps telling me that "else" is an unexpected token and so when I delete it and try "if" or just nothing, then it says { is an unexpected token. I can't seem to figure out where all of the curly brackets go and also I think I'm doing infinite loops because when I go to test it it freezes up.

Comment: What editor/IDE are you using? Any decent one should show you bracket highlighting and make finding extra/missing curly braces a breeze. For the `else`, it can only be used as part of an if-statement: `if () {} else {}`. You can also chain multiple if-elses together: `if () {} else if () {} else if () {} ... else {}`

Comment: Well maybe that's why! Nobody ever mentioned it had to be part of an if statement! We use repl.it to do these assignments which doesn't return anything except for telling you if it's wrong or right, so I keep trying to copy and paste the code into codepen but that's another problem because half the time I cant get it to console.log anything because I can't figure out what part to put in the (). I try all the pieces but it says everything is undefined so idk what I'm doing.

Comment: "I can't figure out what part to put in the ()". You can put any expression within the `()`. The goal is to check if something is truthy or falsey, and then act on that. E.g. `if(10 > 1)` or `if ('dog' == 'Cat')`. Recall from above that `10 > 1` will be `true`, and `'dog' == 'cat'` will be `false`

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a deep breath and relax. I'm a very senior developer and can't tell -- from your examples -- what's going on here. Maybe that's because your instructor is terrible, maybe it's because you've missed some context in your class, and so it's omitted from the question.

I can answer the two questions you've been given. Hopefully it'll be helpful.

First:

I do not know why your materials claim that a `while` loop might be written this way. I've completed the assignment, but it seems very odd. But if they want you to complete it, here's a solution.

```js
// Another way to write a while loop is to have a boolean variable 
// where the condition goes and then test every time if you need to
// change the boolean to false.

// Below we have a variable lessThan5 and it is set to true.
// Create a loop that tests if our variable 'j' is less than 5.
// If it is less than 5 then Increment it by 1. If it is not 
// less than 5 then set our lessThan5 variable to be false.
let lessThan5 = true;
let j = 0;

while(lessThan5) {
  if (j >= 5) {
    lessThan5 = false;
  } else {
    j++;
  }
}
```

Moving on to the second snippet, the second snippet does not, to me, appear to be related to `guessNumberGame` in any way.

And the solution to "Problem 3" seems useless to me. A loop that doesn't do anything is not useful in real life.

That said, the solution to "Problem 3" is as follows:

```js
// Problem 3
// We will give you a number through the 'num' parameter
// Create a while loop that will loop 'num' amount of times.
// For example if num is 3 then your while loop should loop 3 times
// If num is 20 then the loop should loop 20 times.
// Increment k every loop.
let k = 0;
function keepLooping(num) {
  while(k < num) {
    k++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I just need instruction on every little piece of everything and a lot of this seems so vague. Like "Don't worry about why this says what it says, just do it" and I'm like but, why? There have already been a few things that haven't been explained, but expected to do for a project that turns out it was next week's info (little stuff like how to wrap divs). And nothing about sums or other math equation stuff has been "explained" in the recent videos for this, but it's on this week's assignments to do. idk I think I keep doing infinite loops so that's not helping.

Comment: I will say reading this the second time, the "terminate a while loop while flipping a flag" technique actually isn't that odd. What's odd is using it for a conditional like "less than 5" but perhaps that was an attempt to keep it simple. Not the example I'd use.

And the second loop should at least *do* something. (Print "I can count up to <number>!" each time through or something.) Otherwise it's just wasting electricity.